# When mouse enters the top part of the window do something

Tags: javascript, mouseenter

I'm using this code to detect when the mouse enters the top section of the window and when not.

```js
$(window).on('mouseenter',function(e){
  if ( e.pageY < 40 ) {
    $('.change').addClass('color')
  } else {
    $('.change').removeClass('color')
  }
});
```

```css
span{
  color:black
}
.color{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="change">COLOR</div>
```

The problem is that it is a bit buggy especially when it comes to the `else` part.

I was wondering if this is the correct approach or there is a better one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the else you shall check if the element that you expect to have that class, does really have it, in elseway you will try to remove that class to an element that doesn't have it.

Comment: Can you please post your actual code so that we can analyze what might be happening?

Comment: Window mouseenter will trigger each time the mouse is over the page, anywhere, not only on top. I would suggest using a div on the top section of the document and bind the event to the div

Comment: @ControlAltDel there you go

Comment: The `mouseenter` event is only triggered when the mouse initially moves into the DOM ... I believe the event you're looking for is `mousemove` so that the event callback gets triggered more frequently based on actual mouse movement, not just when the mouse initially enters the screen